# How do I change the color of a div if two values don't match?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm creating a pricing calculator with jQuery, and I have an input where the user enters their budget, and a div where a number is generated.  I want to compare the two numbers and if the estimate is within the user's budget, I want the estimate to turn green, and if it is not, I want it to turn red. The catch is, I only want the comparison to take place if the user has entered a budget. If the budget input is blank, it should not compare.  I have this so far:

```
<input id="budget" type="text" />
<span class="estimate">$0</span>

var budget = $("#budget").val();
var estimate = $(".estimate").text();

    if(!(budget >= estimate)){
        estimate.css('color','#ff0000');
}
```

With the above, I was trying to get the value and the text from the two items, and then check if they were greater than or equal to each other. Any ideas?

Comment: If you add the monetary dollar sign by using a css `:before { content: "$"; }` rule, the comparisons will be easier...

Answer (score 2):

Compare actual numbers, and set the CSS on an element, not the value you get

```
$(function() {
    var budget   = parseInt( $("#budget").val(), 10 );
    var estimate = parseInt( $(".estimate").text().replace(/\D/g,''), 10);

    if ( budget < estimate ) {
        $(".estimate").css('color','#ff0000');
    }
});
```

The dollarsign makes it NaN, so that should be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Your `estimate` variable targets `$(".estimate").text()` which is the text content. Use `$(".estimate").css('color','#ff0000');` to change the color of that element.